# Removing users from Firebase error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I deleted the user from Firebase console and there is no user in it. But when I do the following request:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
      FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
      if (user != null) {
         // User is signed in
         firebaseAuthUser = true;
      } else {
         // User is signed out
         firebaseAuthUser = false;
      }
   }
};
```

I see the user is signed in. How can this be? The user isn't in Firebase database but the user is "signed in"!

Comment: because it is not delete from Authentication folder of firebase console of your project.if you delete than your problem will be solved.

Comment: There is no user in Authentication console. How can I delete user if the user doesn't exist in console? I used Authentication console to delete